# knitr: Nested child-documents

Tags: r, nested, knitr

Reading this

> You can freely nest one Rnw document in the other, as long as the nested structure is clear in your mind.

on http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/  I thought one can nest a Rnw-file in an already nested Rnw-document. Unfortunately I did not manage to do so (probably due to a lack of knowledge). For example I've got the following directories and files:

Working directory

_ test.Rnw

_ Subfolder

_ _ subdoc.Rnw

_ _ Subsubfolder

_ _ _ subsubdoc.Rnw

including:

```
% test.Rnw

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<child1, child='Subfolder/subdoc.Rnw', eval=TRUE>>=
@


\end{document}
```

... and in subdoc.Rnw I want to include another Rnw:

```
% subdoc.Rnw

<<child1, child='Subsubfolders/subsubdoc.Rnw', eval=TRUE>>=
@
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message when knitting test.Rnw:

> ...
>
> label: child1 (with options) 
>   List of 2
>   $ child: chr "Subsubfolder/subsubdoc.Rnw"
>   $ eval : logi TRUE
>
> Warnung in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
>    kann Datei 'Subsubfolder/subsubdoc.Rnw' nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
>
> Quitting from lines 1-1 (./Subfolder/Subsubfolder/subsubdoc.Rnw)
>
> Quitting from lines 2-4 (./Subfolder/Subsubfolder/subsubdoc.Rnw)
>
> Fehler in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : 
>     kann Verbindung nicht öffnen
>
> Calls: knit ... process_group.block -> call_block -> lapply -> FUN -> knit -> readLines
>
> Ausführung angehalten

which means, that knitr isn't able to open 'Subsubfolder/subsubdoc.Rnw' as there is no such file or directory. Changing the code in subdoc.Rnw to

```
<<child1, child='Subfolder/Subsubfolders/subsubdoc.Rnw', eval=TRUE>>=
@
```

doesn't make sense either, because now knitr is trying to set the wd to

```
./Subfolder/Subfolder/Subsubfolder/subsubdoc.Rnw
```

. Compiling test.Rnw without the child-input in subdoc.Rnw works perfectly.

I'm using knitr_1.5, R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit).

Comment: Sounds like a bug; I'm investigating into it. Perhaps it works when you put all child documents under the same directory. The nested sub-directories are tricky for both knitr and LaTeX.